# Activate another Form

Tags: c#

From Form1 I've been opening Form2. If I then click on a button or whatever in Form1, I want Form2 to be activated. Something like

```
Form2.Activate();
```

But that just gives me errors.

This is my code right now:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // first I click here
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // then here, to activate it
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Activate();
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors ?

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Activate()' 660

Comment: Where do you create Form2 inside Form1 ?

Comment: you should have created an instance of Form2 inside form1 prior to calling activate

Comment: Both the windows are up when I use the Form2.Activate();

Comment: if that worked than add it as answer to your own question , or check up the answer that helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the Form2 reference out to **Class** level so it can be accessed from both button1 and button2.

Something like...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 f2 = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // first I click here
    {
        if (f2 == null || f2.IsDisposed)
        {
            f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            ActivateForm2();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // then here, to activate it
    {
        ActivateForm2();
    }

    private void ActivateForm2()
    {
        if (f2 != null && !f2.IsDisposed)
        {
            if (f2.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            f2.Activate();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're having that error because Activate method should be called from an instance of the Form2 class not the Form2 class its self, Activate() is not a Static method, You have to instantiate the Form2 class first, this event handler is for a button click on the first Form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }
```

this was to show the form, to activate it and make it the main one showed to you, you can than call the Activate() method to that instance, like

```
form2.Show();
form2.Activate();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to create an instance of a class in order to access instance methods. Basically, the instance is created via a constructor call, like this:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
```

However, the method to show newly created form is this one:

```
form2.Show();
```